# Python(pip): Module Not Found, after installing my own package from pypi

Tags: setuptools, python-packaging

So i have created this package called footyplots and have uploaded it to PyPi. It has installed successfully on my machine.

[image]

Here is my setup file.

[image]

Here is the directory tree.
[image]

Here is the error when I am importing it.
[image]

I don't know what's wrong. Can somebody help.

Comment: Your `setup.py` is missing the `packages` argument to `setuptools.setup` function call. -- And seems like you don't need the `package_dir` argument.

Comment: So that means I have to add `packages='footyplots'` and remove `package_dir`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `setup.py` is missing the `packages` argument to the `setuptools.setup` function call. You might also want to double check the `package_dir` argument, you might not need it at all.

Try:

- either `packages=['footyplots']`
- or `packages=setuptools.find_packages()`

Comment: So I have to add `packages=['footyplots']` to the setup function ?

Comment: Yes try adding and send the output

Comment: As I have updated the setup.py file how can I be able to reflect changes on PyPi as the packages was initially uploaded.